# MySQL query group by and count on multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table (`voters`) of voter data in the following format:

```
id | name | gender | const
```

I need to output the following:

```
const | no. of female voters | no. of male voters | total no. of voters
```

`order by` no. of female voters.

I could only come up with this query:

```
select const,count(*) from voters where gender='f' group by const order by count(*) desc
```

How do I get other two counts too? const means constituency, gender can be either 'm' or 'f'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mysql you can do this

```
select const,
count(*),
sum(gender='f') female_voters,
sum(gender='m') male_voters
from voters 
group by const 
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: Cool. I just did order by sum(gender='f') and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid Is there any simple way to also show percentage of female voters in another column?

Comment: @Naveed you can calculate % of females as  `(sum(gender='f')/count(*)) * 100`

Comment: Yes but how to display it as a column

Comment: In above query add it like`(sum(gender='f')/count(*)) * 100 as somecolumnname`

Comment: @Naveed Read my comment again i have used full expression not aliases